# My javascript code for mapping splits the word by character and doesn't read the whole word in input

Tags: javascript

I am creating a type of translator in which user enters a specific alphanumeric character or word and the translator shows a pre-defined output against it.

Example:

If someone enters capital A,
it outputs Apple

This works for single character input but if I map a whole word to be replaced with another word, my code is not working properly.

Here is my code:

Input field:

```
output.innerHTML=finalText.trim()}var outHtml='<div class="text-detail"><div class="row element-inner single-element"><div class="col-md-11 col-10 position-initial heading-main"><div class="font-style-name"><span>Cirlce Outline Text</span></div></div><div class="col-md-1 col-2 button-main"><button class="ml-auto copy-btn btn_cpy col-md-1 col-12 button_copy integration-checklist__copy-button" data-clipboard-text="'+applyCharMap(Ahmad,text)+'" data-clipboard-action="copy"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i>COPY</button></div><div class="col-md-12 col-12 position-initial text-area-outer"><div class="font-pre col-md-12 col-12 signature text-area-inner"><textarea class="text-area-main">'+applyCharMap(Ahmad,text)+'</textarea></div></div></div></div>';output.innerHTML=outHtml}
```

Code that splits the characters:

```
function applyCharMap(map, text) {
    var out = "";
    var _iteratorNormalCompletion = !0;
    var _didIteratorError = !1;
    var _iteratorError = undefined;
    try {
        for (var _iterator = text.split("")[Symbol.iterator](), _step; 
          !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); 
          _iteratorNormalCompletion = !0) {
            var c = _step.value;
            if (map[c] !== undefined) out += map[c];
            else if (map[c.toLowerCase()] !== undefined) out += map[c.toLowerCase()];
            else out += c
        }
    } catch (err) {
        _didIteratorError = !0;
        _iteratorError = err
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return != null) {
                _iterator.return()
            }
        } finally {
            if (_didIteratorError) {
                throw _iteratorError
            }
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

What I want to achieve (first is input and after ":" is output

```
var Ahmad = {
  "you": "yaseelf",
  "I": "meseelf",
  "to": "yagatue",
  "the": "dee",
  "a": "nako",
  "and": "alakahso",
  "that": "dat",
  "it": "dating",
  "of": "anaufo",
  "me": "da-mee",
  "what": "waah",
  "is": "ugataku",
  "in": "uginoko",
  "this": "dees",
  "know": "ka-noe",
  "I'm": "meselpa",
  "for": "gafor",
  "no": "refuso",
  "have": "hanave",
  "my": "itake",
  "don't": "refusio",
  "just": "Kunusti",
  "not": "refinaki",
  "not": "refinaki",
  "do": "gajadoo",
  "be": "ukoh",
  "on": "skino",
  "your": "giorza",
  "was": "dasava",
  "we": "garnatoupe",
  "it's": "itajon",
  "with": "witaki",
  "so": "yasio",
  "but": "bahut",
  "all": "alli",
  "well": "vaheil",
  "are": "majare",
  "he": "erono",
  "oh": "eeono",
  "about": "hajabon",
  "right": "gaso",
  "you're": "nuer",
  "get": "kles"
};
```

So what will happen is when someone enters "you", it should output "yaseelf"

But, currently it just shows the output for each character instead of the whole replacement.

Hope experts can help solve this problem.

P.S. Similar code example can be found [here](https://font.emojiss.com/js/fancy_text%20_circled.js)

Regards,

Ahmad

Comment: Your first code snippet seems incomplete. There are stray braces that don't correlate to other braces.

Comment: Live example of similar character mapping is here (https://font.emojiss.com/circled.html) but, it also doesn't show the word based mapping;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are built in functions to split characters and words.  You're re-inventing the wheel.  Your example doesn't seem complete or at least is hard to work with, so I made a simplified version that should get you going.  It uses `split` and `join`.

```js
let translator = {
  "you": "yaseelf",
  "I": "meseelf",
  "to": "yagatue",
  "the": "dee"
};

var button = document.querySelector('#button');
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let words = input.value.split(' ');
  let translated = words.map(word => translator[word] || word);
  output.innerHTML = translated.join(' ');
})
```

```html
<input id='input' type=text value='Lets go to the park' />
<button id='button'>translate</button>

<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Great and simplified example but, is there any way to loop this like a single page shows multiple input fields with each having different words. So each page can show 5 different combinations similar to what you did above with 1. 

Sorry, I am still learning so might sound like a child :)